# iOs 9 UIPickerView selection/pick delay

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I am using UIPickerView in my iOS 9 app. I would like to give user some time to change selection. What I mean is let's say user selected row, and should be able to change selection during some short time. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's preventing them from picking another value from the picker?

Comment: From the way you describe it they should already be able to do that no problem. Do you have any code as well?

Comment: I got complain saying that "it picks value too fast". Code is using standard delegate methods implementation. Unfortunately I cannot post actual code here.